# Useful symbols shortcut for Windows users ✔

Tags: discussion

Pressing `Windows key` + `.` or `;` will open up a "emoji menu" with a lot of useful symbols that you can use in your Q/A.

[image]

Comment: (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞  ╰(\*°▽°\*)╯

Answer (score 5):

To add on to this, I use [WinCompose](http://wincompose.info/) and would recommend it to anyone who needs to type any sort of symbols frequently. (No affiliation, I just appreciate the project.)

What it is is basically XCompose for Windows, so I can type, for instance, [compose], [a], [e] and get out æ, or more usefully for engineers, [compose], [*], [<any letter>] produces the Greek alphabet "equivalent" of that letter, so [compose], [*], [m] for μ for instance.

You can define custom sequences, too, for any symbols that aren't included in the standard ones, or that you don't like the default sequence for. It works the same as XCompose, right down to having a .XCompose file (well, .XCompose.txt, because windows, but you get the idea).

(I have my left windows key set to be the compose key, as I don't use the windows key very often. You can also use things like scroll lock, the menu key, one of your alt keys, etc.)

Comment: Another happy user here, but mostly because I prefer a US keyboard but sometimes have to type in my native language with a slightly different mapping. I didn't know it could take XCompose config files!

Comment: @pipe Yeah! I believe it just looks for a file called C:/Users/(your username)/.XCompose.txt? You might be able to configure where it looks, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Hearth WinCompose attempts to load `%USERPROFILE%/.XCompose` and `%USERPROFILE%/.XCompose.txt` (among others). Since it's open source you can change it to your liking. You'll find the `LoadSequences()` method in `./wincompose/settings/Settings.cs`.

Comment: @Velvel Oh, good to know!